# How to replace the TextBox Caret

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a text box binded with a mobile number and takes - after each 3 charecters.say max characters for mobile number would be 10 and after 3 character a - would be shown (Say example i have 1234567890 )(this mobile number would be replaced with 123-456-7890).

My question here is i need to remove - from the text box and make it an empty.can any one help me in this.this is all done in C#
This is my code which i have tried.

this is associated property i have set

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AssociatedElementProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AssociatedElement", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(NumericKeyBoard), null);

this.caretPosition = associatedTextBox.SelectionStart;
if (associatedTextBox.Tag.ToString() == "mobile" && associatedTextBox.Text.Substring(this.caretPosition - 1, 1) == "-")
{
     associatedTextBox.Text = associatedTextBox.Text.Remove(this.caretPosition - 1, 1);
     this.caretPosition--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a modified TextBox Control like the [MaskedTextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox)

Comment: this cannot be changed.it should be done with the same code like above

Comment: This is just a guess, but take a look at the MaskedTextProvider from the System.ComponentModel Namespace (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.maskedtextprovider(v=vs.100).aspx), maybe you can isolate the masking function